# Classification of two-dimensional complex lattices

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules, integer-lattices, crystallography

A complex lattice consists of a pair of $\mathbb{R}$-linearly independent vectors of the real-vector space $\mathbb{C}$. We call two lattices $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$ and $(\mu_1,\mu_2)$ equivalent if $\mathbb{Z}\lambda_1+\mathbb{Z}\lambda_2= \mathbb{Z}\mu_1+\mathbb{Z}\mu_2$. Is there a classification of equivalence classes of complex lattices? In particular I am interested whether any lattice admits an equivalent lattice of a "nice"(to be specified) type? That is, whether there are "canonical" representatives of any equivalence class of lattices? Certainly for any lattice there is an equivalent lattice $(\mu_1,\mu_2)$ with $Im(\mu_1)\geq0$ and $Im(\mu_2)\geq0$ (by reflecting at $0$, if necessary). But can the position of $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ be even further restricted?

Online I found mention of the crystallographic restriction theorem, which might be relevant. I have not been able to find a good source on this theorem though. So I'd also be happy about a good reference.

Comment: For chemistry see [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/151897/why-are-there-exactly-5-types-of-two-dimensional-lattices-and-what-distinguishe). These are cocompact lattices (what you call crystallographic). From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bravais_lattice):"*Two Bravais lattices are often considered equivalent if they have isomorphic symmetry groups. In this sense, there are 5 possible Bravais lattices in 2-dimensional space*. Wikipedia lists many  good references.

Comment: Thanks, I found the chemistry post rather wanting. There is neither a proof nor a clear definition of the term "lattice". Anyways, is a Bravais lattice in two-dimensional space the same as what I call simply a lattice above? Do you have a good reference for a proof of the classification of Bravais lattices? The terminology on wikipedia (e.g. centered or primitive Bravais lattice) is not properly introduced as far as I can see. Besides it seems to me that they always fix one vectors defining a lattice to lie on the real axis. But not any lattice is equivalent to a lattice of that form, right?

Comment: Only after a suitable rotation, this holds …-

Comment: I did: "We call two lattices $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$ and $(\mu_1,\mu_2)$ equivalent …"

Comment: See again [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(group)) for a classification in dimension $2$, i.e., for $\Bbb C\cong \Bbb R^2$: "There are five 2D lattice types as given by the crystallographic restriction theorem." The standard reference is Conway-Sloane, but there are many other references (just google).

Comment: Searching I found, for example,  [these notes](http://purple.univ-littoral.fr/~boris/prepub/LZbookFull_R.pdf), and [these ones](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~tkc/GeometryandGroups/GeometryandGroups.pdf) online.

Comment: Especially the lecture notes in the first link are quite helpful, many thanks!